# Conjunction of two possessives with different prepositions

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

Consider this sentence:

> In our work, they are mainly textual elements within the content, which serve as the starting point [ <s>of a data region</s> ] or distinctive features within a data region.

I left out "of a data region" as it is in the second part of conjunction, however in that part it has "within" preposition. Is yet my sentence grammatical and natural?

How about:

> In our work, they are mainly textual elements within the content, which serve as the starting point of a data region or distinctive features within **them**.

is it "them" or "it"?

Comment: "Serve as the starting point" is fine, but **serve as the distinctive features* isn't. Do you mean "serve to mark" instead of "serve as"?

Comment: @JohnLawler yes, I think  *they serve as starting point of a data region or they are distinctive features of a data region (within them).*

Comment: @JohnLawler Without knowing what "they" are here -- other than that they are "textual elements" --  I don't know how you could say that "they" cannot be "distinctive features".

Comment: I didn't say they couldn't _be_ distinctive features; I said they couldn't _serve as_ distinctive features. The first clause separates the texual elements from the content (whatever those are, too). Easiest fix if you wanted to keep that anyway, would be to add _of_ before _distinctive_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Right!, I change it to "marker", *In our work, an anchor is mainly a textual element on the page, which serves as the starting or ending point of a data region, or a **distinctive marker** within it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to remove a repetition of an "object clause" (as it were), like in your example

> ...which serve as blah ***of*** *blahblah* or blew ***within*** *blabblah*.

but with different prepositions, you could use this technique:

> ...which serve as blah ***of***, or blew ***within***, *blabblah*.

(note the commas).  Your sentence then becomes

> In our work, they are mainly textual elements within the content, which serve as the starting point of, or distinctive features within, a data region.